# How do I copy a SQL Server table with triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to copy a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table `A1` to create a clone table `A1Clone` (empty table). Is there any way to do this operation in one shot? Thanks.

Edited:

I tried through SSMS, DB level, `Generate Scripts`, and I'm able to generate scripts with advanced options to enable scripts to create triggers and indexes.

[image: Advanced scripting options]

Wondering if there is any other shortcut to copy over the whole table object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking ,how to copy table related objects like indexes,triggers in one go..you can't do that by normal ways like select into...Your options

1. generate scripts of existing object,on which you want to perform operation..
2. normal way of creating entirely